# How do we know that there exists a quantum circuit whose output distribution is #P-hard to calculate?

Tags: random-quantum-circuit

I am trying to understand the random quantum circuit sampling arguments for recent Google experiment, but struggling to understand why there exists a family of quantum circuit whose output distribution is #P-hard to calculate exactly. Papers in this topics just show how to reduce average case random circuit sampling to exact random circuit sampling, but does not provides details of the #P-hardness of exact quantum circuit sampling. Could anybody provide detailed arguments for the fact that there exists a family of quantum circuit whose output distribution is #P-hard to calculate exactly?

Thanks.